# Syntax of list item classes

Tags: html, css, width, html-lists

I have this unordered list and I want each list item to be a certain width (because the text of the list items varies a lot in lenght, I have, I think, to specify the width for each individual list item). Most of the HTML cannot be edited by me (I'm modifying a template), but I can edit the CSS all I want (I think), and, using Inspect Element in my browser, I found out that the HTML for the list item looks like this:

```
<li class="w-menu-item wsite-nav-3" style="position: relative;">
```

I therefore figured out that

```
#navigation .w-menu-item wsite-nav-3 {
width: 5%;
}
```

in the CSS would let me control the width of the list element on the screen, but this does not seem to be happening. (#navigation refers to the div that contains the list.) Am I getting the syntax wrong, or is there some other issue here? If not this, then how do I go about specifying the width of the list and its elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `.`, which indicates that `wsite-nav-3` is a class name:

```css
#navigation .w-menu-item.wsite-nav-3 {
/*                      ^            */
    width: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
#navigation .w-menu-item.wsite-nav-3 {
width: 5%;
}
```